# Realm.io One way sync

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm want to develop an application, which collects some measurements and uploads to the Realm.io platform, and after uploading I want to delete from the device, and keep the datas just in the server(Realm platform). Is it possible? Can somebody provide some example?
Thank you!

Comment: No, but you can add a field like `isDeleted` to your schema, and use Partial Sync ("query-based synchronization") to download only query data where `isDeleted == false`

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, but I don’t really understand how can this help for me to delete all data from the device.

Comment: Thank you again @EpicPandaForce, your suggestion works. I have tried it and works very well.